# Keep the date value in a html form after it has been submitted

Tags: html, forms, input

I have created this form which I have placed in the Wordpress divi theme code module on a page. It is used to return the stock availability for my shop that is connected to a 3rd party api.

After the form is submitted how do I get it to keep displaying the values that were submitted.

```
<p>Enter your Event Dates</p><br>

<form class="Dates" action="" method="post">

<span>
  <label for="date_from">Date From:</label>
  <input type="date" id="date_from" name="date_from" value="dd-MM-YYY">
</span>

<span>
  <label for="date_to">Date To:</label>
  <input type="date" id="date_to" name="date_to" value="dd_MM-YYY"><br>
</span>

<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
<input type="date" id="date_from" name="date_from" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['date_from'] ? $_POST['date_from'] : '' ?>">
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Unfortunately it didn't work it just went back to showing today's date after hitting submit.

Comment: @Zalanca Maybe a javascript changes this value to current date time. You could add another javascript at the bottom or add another input for checking it.

Comment: Thanks again. I haven't added any javascript its just in a html code module inside the theme builder. Where would I add javascript and what would I need to add? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can try writing a new script under all javascript definitions. Page must .php

```
<script>
document.getElementById("date_from").value = '<?php echo isset($_POST['date_from'] ? $_POST['date_from'] : '' ?>';
```

Comment: Do I but that in the functions.php file?

Comment: If your theme supports adding custom javascript you should do it from there. If not, you can write it under the </body> section of the /wp-content/themes/yourthemedirectory/footer.php file in your website files. I must say it is not a good method.

Comment: Thank you again. I am open to be redirected to any suggestions of a better method to use. I don't think my theme supports custom javascript.

Comment: I have consulted my theme documents and it says to add javascript like this.

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("p").click(function(){
    jQuery(this).hide();
  });
});

So given that format does this look right

<script>

  JQuery(document).getElementById("date_from").value = '<?php echo isset($_POST['date_from'] ? $_POST['date_from'] : '' ?>';
  
</script>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jquery you should use this format:

```
$(function(){
 $('#date_from').val('submitted value');
});
```

but jquery doesn't know what was sent before. So you can update your script like this:

```
$(function(){
 $('#date_from').on("keyup",function(){
    window.localStorage.setItem('date',$(this).val());
 });

 $('#date_from').val(window.localStorage.getItem("date"));
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help unfortunately this did not work. You mentioned there was a better way of doing this?

Comment: Simply submitting the form data does not change the value of the submitting elements after the page is reloaded. These values ​​must be being changed by default somewhere. You can find out where and how this change took place by looking at your functions and scripts. Basically, the browser's developer tools (eg google chrome can be opened with the F12 key.) can help you with this. For more detailed information aboud how to debug javascript by chrome https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/